# "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list' " error in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, valueerror

I keep getting the error "only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted" after initialization of `A` in the following code. Can someone tell me what's wrong or how I should fix this? Here's my code that I'm using to define a function:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([10.0, 11.0, 15.0, 17.0, 12.0, 15.0, 18.0, 34.0, 14.0, 12.0, 19.0, 15.0],
             [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
             [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
             [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 31.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
             [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
             [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 20.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
             [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 20.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
             [20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
             [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
             [20.0, 25.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0])

B = np.array([0.01, 0.03, 0.05, 0.07, 0.08, 0.10, 0.13, 0.16, 0.20, 0.21, 0.25, 0.30])

def bonus(A,B):
    A = np.array([10.0, 11.0, 15.0, 17.0, 12.0, 15.0, 18.0, 34.0, 14.0, 12.0, 19.0, 15.0],
                 [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
                 [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
                 [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 31.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
                 [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
                 [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 20.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
                 [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 20.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
                 [20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
                 [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
                 [20.0, 25.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0])

    B = np.array([0.01, 0.03, 0.05, 0.07, 0.08, 0.10, 0.13, 0.16, 0.20, 0.21, 0.25, 0.30])

    C = (A*B)
    return(C)

bonus(A,B)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add extra brackets at the beginning and end of A. It should be:

```
A = np.array([[10.0, 11.0, 15.0, 17.0, 12.0, 15.0, 18.0, 34.0, 14.0, 12.0, 19.0, 15.0],
             [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
             [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
             [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 31.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
             [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
             [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 20.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
             [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 20.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
             [20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
             [20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
             [20.0, 25.0, 21.0, 23.0, 27.0, 22.0, 25.0, 21.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0]])
```

Comment: Why add the extra brackets?

Comment: Because A is a 2-dimensional array, which is an array whose elements are arrays themselves. so A should look like [ [...],[...],.....,[....] ].